# How do I directly upload the images to FTP from the given image path(Live URL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am working on the task that, I need to upload the images to particular FTP by using C# coding from given live path.

At the moment I done it, but to upload images on FTP I take round trip of (download the images 
on local and then upload it to live by using code).

I want the solution to directly upload images to to ftp without downloading it.

eg. From given path http://www.globalgear.com.au/products/bladesbook_sml.jpg

I need this image to upload.

**hello, I am rectifying my question more, I want to fetch Small and large images from this URL(globalgear.com.au/productfeed.xml) and upload directly to FTP without downloading it on local. –**

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

Perhabs this will work:

```
 // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
    byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();
```

Comment: hello, I am rectifying my question more, I want to fetch Small and large images from this URL(http://www.globalgear.com.au/productfeed.xml) and upload directly to FTP without downloading it on local.